# how to convert this data coming from server to json format in android?

Tags: java, android, json

I have a data of this format coming from server in android.

`112.198.78.80,2016-12-28 01:00:00.791600
175.157.80.115,2016-12-28 01:00:00.791600
49.33.40.172,2016-12-28 01:00:00.791600
27.97.201.244,2016-12-28 01:00:00.791600`

but actually after receiving this data i need to convert to json format  in android

`[{"112.198.78.80":"175.157.80.115","2016-12-28 01:00:00.791600":"2016-12-28 01:00:00.791600"},
{"112.198.78.80":"49.33.40.172","2016-12-28 01:00:00.791600":"2016-12-28 01:00:00.791600"},
{"112.198.78.80":"27.97.201.244","2016-12-28 01:00:00.791600":"2016-12-28 01:00:00.791600"}]`

like this and show the events on the map.So now I want to know how to convert this data to json format in android.can anyone please help as I am new to android and maps?

Comment: Read a pair on lines, split on the comma, and then format per your requirements. What are you really asking for? Us to do it for you?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to create a JSONArray of JSONObjects
Depending on how you receive your data, do this inside a for loop or a while or whatever, but the idea is:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
obj.put("112.198.78.80","2016-12-28 01:00:00.791600"); //Add all the other elements 
arr.put(obj);
```